# Get SQL Results - JSONarray cannot be converted to JSONobject

Tags: php, json

I have modified my code over a couple of hours and I just cannot seem to parse value from android and use it in php, I alway get JSONarray cannot be converted to JSONobject.

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$con=mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");

if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) {

     $value = $_POST["json"]; 
     $decoded_value = json_decode($value);

    $sql = "SELECT * from table WHERE Code = '".$decoded_value->{'msg'}."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $json = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $json['myarray'][]=$row;
        }
    }

mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 

}
?>
```

Comment: Is that a mysql_* function I see..

Answer (score 1):

```
json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

The json_encode function has multiple parameters that you can pass in order to modify the encoding method ([check it out here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)). In your instance, there is the option to force the encoding to be in an object form, rather than the default of either array or object.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.